# Visual Studio 2017 Stops Debugging When Navigating Away From Site Being Debugged

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, iis-express

This has been driving me crazy...

Running a solution works with no problems. I can navigate within the application with no issues. The problem arises when I navigate to a site outside of the debugging site, i.e. I go to a site outside of localhost. The reason to go outside the site is to authenticate the user to their Azure AD which brings them to microsoftonline.com. It's not just that site either, any other site causes the same problem. What happens is the debug session silently stops. IIS Express does exit with iisexpress.exe has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

I've tried repairing Visual Studio and that appeared to temporarily fix the issue.

The issue happens on all solutions, including new empty ones.

**UPDATE:**
If I run VS in Administrator mode it appears to work, but this is not a viable solution.

Comment: This is most likely happening because Visual Studio has attached a debugger to the browser so that JavaScript can be debugged.  Leaving the domain of the app causes the browser to recycle the process, killing the debugger.  Turning that off would probably fix the issue, but would leave you unable to debug JavaScript inside Visual Studio.

Comment: This just started to happen. I just tried running VS in administrator mode and it works fine, but I don't want to run it in admin mode...

Comment: this is annoying especially if you are using third party authentication. When app start in debugging and redirect for authentication, the debugger stops. For me it happening with IE 11 but not from chrome. However, is i start Visual Studio in Admin mode the it works with IE 11 as well